# Rails/MySQL only one value for attribute is being saved in column, to DB

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This is going to be a hard issue to give input on so I will give as much detail as I can. Below is the exact issue I am trying to figure out. For some reason when I save, experience is deleting all other values in the column and writing it in the day that it was updated. I just got all the other values saving, but I left them out of the table for clarity. The weirdest part is that budget and experience are set up EXACTLY the same but are not saving the same unfortunately. Below are more specifics on the issue.

## Any insight on what might be going on is greatly appreciated.

```
+------+--------+-----------+------------+-----------------+
| id   | bar_id | day       | budget     | experience      |
+------+--------+-----------+------------+-----------------+
| 1816 |    369 | monday    | LOW BUDGET |                 |
| 1817 |    369 | tuesday   | low budget |                 |
| 1818 |    369 | wednesday | low budget | IN CONVERSATION |
| 1819 |    369 | thursday  | low budget |                 |
| 1820 |    369 | friday    | low budget |                 |
| 1821 |    369 | saturday  | low budget |                 |
+------+--------+-----------+------------+-----------------+

+------+--------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
| id   | bar_id | day       | budget     | experience         |
+------+--------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
| 1822 |    369 | monday    | LOW BUDGET |                    |
| 1823 |    369 | tuesday   | low budget |                    |
| 1824 |    369 | wednesday | low budget |                    |
| 1825 |    369 | thursday  | low budget | ON THE DANCE FLOOR |
| 1826 |    369 | friday    | low budget |                    |
| 1827 |    369 | saturday  | low budget |                    |
+------+--------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
```

These are the inputs for the form (View)

```
    <div class="row clearfix">
      <div class="label">Budget</div>
        <div class="mid budget">
        <div class="mid">
          <input class="venProfileInputs caps" name="bar_profile[<%= day %>][budget]" onblur=checkBudVals(this)>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row clearfix">
      <div class="label">Experience</div>
        <div class=" mid">
          <input class="venProfileInputs caps" name="bar_profile[<%= day %>][experience]" onblur=checkExVals(this) /> 
        </div>
      </div>
```

Then it goes into the controller

```
  def update
    @bar = Bar.find(params[:id])
    if @bar.update_attributes(params[:bar])
      @bar.update_profiles(params[:bar_profile])
      redirect_to "/admin", :notice => "Bar was successfully updated."
    else
      render :action => :edit
    end
  end
```

And it gets updated in the model

```
  def update_profiles(params)
    profiles.each {|p| p.destroy }
    
    params[:active_profiles].split(',').each do |profile_day|
      next if profile_day.blank?
      
      add_profile(params[profile_day.to_sym])
      
      # sets up crowd tags
      crowd_tags_ids = params[profile_day.to_sym][:tags]
      unless crowd_tags_ids.blank?
        crowd_tags_ids.split(',').each do |tag_id|
          next if tag_id.strip == ""
          profiles.last.crowd_tags << CrowdTag.find(tag_id)
        end
      end      
      profiles.last.set_crowd_tags
      #need to loop through cf_tags_ids = params[profile_day.to_sym][:cf_tags]
      cf_tags_ids = params[profile_day.to_sym][:cf_tags]
      unless cf_tags_ids.blank?
        # loop through each category 0,1,2,3,4
        cf_tags_ids.each_pair{ |cat, ids|
            #cycle through each id in the current cat and add to crowd fiter tag
            ids.split(',').each do |cf_id|
                next if cf_id.strip == ""
                profiles.last.crowd_filter_tags << CrowdFilterTag.find(cf_id)
            end
          }
      end     
      profiles.last.set_cf_tags
      # below is not working for saving experience
      profiles.last.experience = params[profile_day.to_sym][:experience]
      logger.info "#{profiles.last.inspect}"
      #### Still need to save experience some how, budget seems to be getting saved
      # but only one value for experience is being logged in a single row for each bar_id
      

    end
  end
```

Logger output:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", 
"bar"=>{"name"=>"Rue B", "website"=>"www.ruebnyc.com", "neighbourhood"=>"Greenwich Village",
"street_address"=>"188 Avenue B", "city"=>"New York", "country"=>"US", "state"=>"NY", "zipcode"=>"10009"}, 
"bar_profile"=>{"active_profiles"=>",monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday", 

"monday"=>{"day"=>"monday", "description"=>"", "plan_b"=>"", "capacity"=>"100",    
"rating"=>"5", "budget"=>"LOW BUDGET", "experience"=>"ON THE DANCE FLOOR", 
"cf_tags"=>{"0"=>"83,", "1"=>"127,", "2"=>"120,", "3"=>"111,", "4"=>"128,"}, "tags"=>"16,46,45,"}, 

"tuesday"=>{"day"=>"tuesday", "description"=>"Come after dining hours to mellow out with the Lost Generation of today. Fedora optional.",
"plan_b"=>"", "capacity"=>"", "rating"=>"0", "budget"=>"low budget", "experience"=>"",
"cf_tags"=>{"0"=>"61,", "1"=>"", "2"=>"", "3"=>"", "4"=>""}, "tags"=>""}, 

"wednesday"=>{"day"=>"wednesday", "description"=>"Come after dining hours to mellow out with the Lost Generation of today. Fedora optional.", 
"plan_b"=>"", "capacity"=>"", "rating"=>"0", "budget"=>"low budget", "experience"=>"",
"cf_tags"=>{"0"=>"61,", "1"=>"", "2"=>"", "3"=>"", "4"=>""}, "tags"=>""}, 

"thursday"=>{"day"=>"thursday", "description"=>"Come after dining hours to mellow out with the Lost Generation of today. Fedora optional.", 
"plan_b"=>"", "capacity"=>"", "rating"=>"0", "budget"=>"low budget", "experience"=>"",
"cf_tags"=>{"0"=>"59,", "1"=>"", "2"=>"", "3"=>"", "4"=>""}, "tags"=>""}, 

"friday"=>{"day"=>"friday", "description"=>"Come after dining hours to mellow out with the Lost Generation of today. Fedora optional.", 
"plan_b"=>"", "capacity"=>"", "rating"=>"0", "budget"=>"low budget", "experience"=>"",
"cf_tags"=>{"0"=>"60,", "1"=>"", "2"=>"", "3"=>"", "4"=>""}, "tags"=>""}, 

"saturday"=>{"day"=>"saturday", "description"=>"Come after dining hours to mellow out with the Lost Generation of today. Fedora optional.",
"plan_b"=>"", "capacity"=>"", "rating"=>"0", "budget"=>"low budget", "experience"=>"",
"cf_tags"=>{"0"=>"59,", "1"=>"", "2"=>"", "3"=>"", "4"=>""}, "tags"=>""}, 

"sunday"=>{"day"=>"sunday", "description"=>"", "plan_b"=>"", "capacity"=>"", "rating"=>"",
"budget"=>"", "experience"=>"", "cf_tags"=>{"0"=>"", "1"=>"", "2"=>"", "3"=>"", "4"=>""}, "tags"=>""}}, "id"=>"369"}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell it's doing what it should.  Your log file shows that for every "day" except "monday" "experience" is set to "".   On monday it's set to "ON THE DANCE FLOOR".  Where-as "budget" is set to something on every day.

I'd look at your HTML/JS to see if you are somehow clearing out that field prior to form submission.

Comment: That's the problem, everything looks right but it isn't working correctly... Super irritating. The JS is set up the same on both budget and experience. The problem isn't that it is not saving the value. The issue is for some reason when it saves that value it deletes all other values in that column as shown from the DB tables at the top.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine this really helping any one, but some JQuery somewhere in this huge project was dependent on a specific set up in the html. The "experience" block was missing an additional div that allowed the JS to grab the right value... which is why it kept updating with nil, because the value was not found.

```
        <div class="row clearfix">
          <div class="label">Budget</div>
          <div class="mid budget">
          <div class="mid">
            <input class="venProfileInputs caps" name="bar_profile[<%= day %>][budget]" onblur=checkBudVals(this)>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row clearfix">
          <div class="label">Experience</div>
------>   <div class="mid experience">
          <div class=" mid">
            <input class="venProfileInputs caps" name="bar_profile[<%= day %>][experience]" onblur=checkExVals(this) /> 
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```